# How to increment a string variable within a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, grep

I want a loop that can find the letter that ends words most frequently in multiple languages and output the data in columns.
So far I have

```
count="./wordlist/french/fr.txt ./wordlist/spanish/es.txt ./wordlist/german/de.$
lang="French Spanish German Portuguese Italian"
(
echo -e "Language Letter Count"
for i in $count
do
    (for j in {a..z}
        do
            echo -e "LANG" $j $(grep -c $j\> $i)
        done
    ) | sort -k3 -rn | head -1
done
) | column -t
```

I want it to output as shown:

```
Language  Letter  Count
French     e       196195
Spanish    a       357193
German     e       251892
Portuguese a       217178
Italian    a       216125
```

Instead I get:

```
Language  Letter  Count
LANG      z       0
LANG      z       0
LANG      z       0
LANG      z       0
LANG      z       0
```

The words files have the format:
`Word Freq(#)` where the word and its frequency are delimited by a space.

This means I have 2 problems;
First, the `grep` command is not handling the argument `$j\>` to find a character at the end of a word. I have tried using `grep -E $j\>` and `grep '$j\>'` and neither worked.

The second problem is that I don't know how to output the name of the language (in the variable `lang`). Nesting another `for` loop did not work when I tried it like this (or with i and k in the opposite order):

```
(
for i in $count
do
    for k in $lang
    do
        for j in {a..z}
        do
             echo -e $k $j $(grep -c $j\> $i)
        done
        ) | sort -k3 -rn | head -1
done
done
) | column -t
```

Since this outputs multiples of the name of the language "`$k`" in places where it does not belong.

I know that I can just copy and paste the loop for each language, but I would like to extend this to every language.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you paste a couple of lines from, say, two of the wordlist files to test against?

Comment: even if this worked, wouldn't it output the wrong numbers? e.g. if your word-count file has three entries: `is 1000; xertz 1; showbiz 1;` the result would be `z 2` (rather than`s 1000`)

Comment: Yeah, Umlaute, it would `z 2` which is what I want since I want to count the frequency and display the character that most frequently ends a word within the file itself. 

And, roelofs, a sample of the file is shown here:
`de 1622928
je 1622619
est 1348809
pas 1128894
le 1093232`

so within this file itself, e most commonly ends a word. Sorry for the misconception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `grep` word boundaries

To make special delimiters (e.g. `\>` for word-end) work with `egrep` when being called from the shell, you should put them into `"`quotes`"`.

```
 count=$(egrep -c "${char}\>" "${file}")
```

Btw, you really should use *double quote* (`"`), because single quotes will prevent variable-expansion. (e.g. in `j="foo"; k='$j\>'`, the first character of `k`'s value will be `$` rather than `f`)

## Language name display

Getting the right language string is a bit more tricky; here's a few suggestions:

- Derive the displayed language from the path of the wordlist:

  ```
  lang=${file%/*}
  lang=${lang##*/}
  ```

  With bash (though not with dash and some other shells) you might even do `lang=${lang^}` to capitalize the string.
- Lookup the proper language name in a dictionary. `Bash-4` has dictionaries built in, but you can also use filebased dicts:

  ```
  $ cat languagues.txt
  ./wordlist/french/fr.txt Français 
  ./wordlist/english/en.txt English
  ./wordlist/german/de.txt Deutsch

  $ file=./wordlist/french/fr.txt
  $ lang=$(egrep "^${file}/>" languages.txt | awk '{print $2}')
  ```
- You can also iterate over `file,lang` pairs, e.g.

  ```
  languages="french/fr,French spanish/es,Español german/de,Deutsch"
  for l in $languages; do
     file=./wordlist/${l%,*}.txt
     lang=${l#*,}
     # ...
  done
  ```

## Taking word frequencies into account

The third problem I see (though I might misunderstand the problem), is that you are not taking the word frequency into account. e.g. a word *A* that is used 1000 times more often than the word *B* will only get counted once (just like *B*).

You can use `awk` to sum up the word frequencies of matching words:

```
count=$(egrep "${char}\>" "${file}" | awk '{s+=$2} END {print s}')
```

## All Together Now

So a full solution to the problem could look like:

```
languages="french/fr,French spanish/es,Español german/de,Deutsch"

(
echo -e "Language Letter Count"
for l in ${languages}; do
  file=./wordlist/${l%,*}.txt
  lang=${l#*,}

  for char in {a..z}; do
     #count=$(egrep -c "${char}\>" "${file}")
     count=$(egrep "${char}\>" "${file}" | awk '{s+=$2} END {print s}')
     echo ${file} ${char} ${count}
  done | sort -k3 -rn | head -1
done
) | column -t
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully and I learned something new, thanks Umlaute!

Comment: I do have a question if you don't mind,

Can you tell me how you used the `${l%,*}` and `${l#*,}` ? I am still confused about the usage of `%` and `#` within the script, what exactly do they mean?

Comment: @Angelo `man bash` and search for `##` should give you an explanation that is better than anything i could say.